# Mapping for nested fields of type geo point in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Get mapping API made me notice the issue. I don't know whats exactly the problem but i will explain the scenario

1. Define mapping for root level field as Geo point.
2. Get mapping for the same fields results in expected output.
3. Define mapping for nested fields as Geo point.
4. Using get mapping API for the nested field results nothing in case of 0 documents indexed and returns the string type in case of at-least one document in an index.

.........
Mappping
.........
`

```
PUT /loc_index_nw
{
    "mappings": {
        "loc_data_nw": {         
            "properties": {
                "primary_name_nw": {"type": "string"},
                "location_nw": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "id_nw": {"type": "string"},
                "locality_nw": {"type" : "string"},
                "fav_locations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "fields": {
                        "nested_locality_nw": {"type": "geo_point"},
                        "nested_location_type": {"type": "string"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

.........
Get Mapping before indexing any document (get mapping of particular fields only)
.........

```
GET loc_index_nw/_mapping/loc_data_nw/field/fav_locations.nested_location_type,fav_locations.nested_locality_nw
```

.........
Sample Data
.........
`

```
POST /loc_index_nw/loc_data_nw/1
{
    "id_nw":1,
    "primary_name_nw":"National Sarvodaya School",
    "location_nw":{"lat":"19.046304","lon":"72.897536"},
    "locality_nw":"chembur",
    "fav_locations":[
        {
            "nested_location_type": "office",
            "nested_locality_nw": {"lat":"19.04","lon": "72.89"}
        },
        {
            "nested_location_type": "home",
            "nested_locality_nw": {"lat":"19.99","lon": "72.01"}
        }
    ]
}
```

`

`

```
POST /loc_index_nw/loc_data_nw/2
{
    "id_nw":2,
    "primary_name_nw":"Diamond Garden",
    "location_nw":{"lat":"19.053493","lon":"72.899992"},
    "locality_nw":"chembur",
    "fav_locations":[
        {
            "nested_location_type": "park",
            "nested_locality_nw": {"lat":"19.04","lon": "72.89"}
        },
        {
            "nested_location_type": "home",
            "nested_locality_nw": {"lat":"19.99","lon": "72.01"}
        }
    ]
}
```

`

.........
Get Mapping before indexing couple of document (get mapping of particular fields only)
.........

```
GET loc_index_nw/_mapping/loc_data_nw/field/fav_locations.nested_location_type,fav_locations.nested_locality_nw
```

Comment: Please tell us what your problem is.

Comment: field being defined as geo point at root level is working properly, but if the similar field being defined at nested level as geo point is treated as string. hence m not able to apply geo distance filter on nested field

Comment: actually going further it treats field type for every nested field even if i manually define mapping for each nested field. in my case it results all field type to be string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `"fields"` with `"properties"` in your nested mapping definition. So your mapping should look like:

```
PUT /loc_index_nw
{
    "mappings": {
        "loc_data_nw": {         
            "properties": {
                "primary_name_nw": {"type": "string"},
                "location_nw": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "id_nw": {"type": "string"},
                "locality_nw": {"type" : "string"},
                "fav_locations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "nested_locality_nw": {"type": "geo_point"},
                        "nested_location_type": {"type": "string"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried that with your documents it worked fine.

Comment: thanks "Sloan Ahrens". I tried changing the same yesterday night going through the documents and it worked for me.. :)